# Does isotretinoin affects contraception hormonal pills - Ethinylestradiolum, Drospirenonum

Tags: pharmacology

Does isotretinoin affects contraception hormonal pills - Ethinylestradiolum, Drospirenonum? Asking as a pharmacologist not a patient.

Answer (score 2):

My professional knowledge of vitamin A derivatives is limited to preparative aspects and some photochemical properties.

But it seems that the German [Bundesinstitut für Arzneimittel und Medizinprodukte (BfArM)](http://www.bfarm.de/) provides some information in german and english.

I didn't know whether a link to the search would survive the session, so the link above is just to their website and you would need to search yourself in case you're interested.

---

Note: I had a look at the *Fachinformationen* (RTF in German) among the documents "linked".

In this publication, it is very explicitly pointed out that Isotretinoin is a **TERATOGEN** and efficient contraception therefore is absolutely vital (in the truest sense of the word).

It is suggested that patients use **two independent** methods of contraception, of which one should be a "barrier method", e.g. the use of condoms.

Comment: In the link you provided I have found: http://www.bfarm.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/EN/Drugs/vigilance/PSURs/csp/g-j/isotretinoin.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=3

There is no mentioning of interaction between hormonal contraception and isotretinoin.

I found(link at the BOTTOM) "Isotretinoin may reduce the efficacy of these medicines in some women, and they are not 100% reliable. Subcutaneous hormone implants or Mirena® may also be considered." but this is very inexact http://www.dermnetnz.org/treatments/isotretinoin.html

Comment: Could you have a look on that: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15116059

Comment: Please note that I'm not a pharmacologist, I only did some therapeutic drug monitoring in the last millenium. Results and conclusion sound to me like "[...] actually, our data are a bit shaky and we can't really prove a correlation", but better safe than sorry. The "Fachinformationen" (maybe you can run it through a translator) comes to similar conclusions: We're not certain if there's a pharmacological interaction, but if something goes wrong, the sh*t certainly hits the fan.